# Reclaiming my orphan question

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I asked [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/extrapolating-the-amount-of-data-missing-from-the-amount-of-data-partially-missi) about a year ago, but it seems to somehow not have been associated with my account. Could someone please help me reclaim it as mine? That is, could you please merge no-longer-existant-for-some-reason User 2491 with me, User 2495?

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to do anything because @user2491 is 'dead' (at least for us!)... That's probably a question to ask to the SE team directly.

Comment: Despite old, maybe this thread should be tagged as "feature-request".